# Python Runtime error counting words in file

Tags: python, file, runtime-error, word-count

After being faced with a syntax error for some noticeable time and having realised I made a foolish mistake, I proceeded to correct my way only to encounter a runtime error. So far I'm trying to produce a program which is able to read the amount of words from a file, however, instead of counting the number of words the program seems to count the number of letters which is not benefital for the outcome of my program. Please find the appropriate code below. Thanks for any and all contributions!

```
def GameStage02():
global FileSelection                                                                                                                                                                           
global ReadFile
global WordCount
global WrdCount
FileSelection = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("*.txt files", ".txt"),("*.txt files", "")))
with open(FileSelection, 'r') as file:
    ReadFile = file.read()
SelectTextLabel.destroy()                                                                                                                                             
WrdCount=0
for line in ReadFile:
    Words=line.split()
    WrdCount=WrdCount+len(Words)
    print(WrdCount)
GameStage01Button.config(state=NORMAL)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break it down:

`ReadFile = file.read()` will give you a string.

`for line in ReadFile` will iterate over the characters in that string.

`Words=line.split()` will give you a list with one or zero characters in it.

That's probably not what you want. Change

```
ReadFile = file.read()
```

to

```
ReadFile = file.readlines()
```

This will give you a list of lines, which you can iterate over and/or `split` into lists of words.

In addition, note that `file` is not a good variable name (in Python2), because that's already the name of a builtin.

Comment: @ArlidioDobra no problem (see, I'm such a gangster, too).

Answer (score 0):

As a continuation of [timgeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34568581/1849998), here is a working piece of code that does this:

```
import re
#open file.txt, read and 
#split the file content with \n character as the delimiter(basically as lines)
lines = open('file.txt').read().splitlines() 
count = 0
for line in lines:
  #split the line with whitespace delimiter and get the list of words in the line
  words = re.split(r'\s', line) 
  count += len(words)
print count
```